# Partial Searches in Sql Server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, full-text-search, sql-like

what is the best way to do search in a sql database, my website I am building will  be doing lots of user driven searches.

I first thought about using sql server full text search but now I am finding it seems to not support partial matches

Say I got this data.

```
Procter & Gamble
Google
Stackoverflow 
A&M Records
```

and I want to try to find anything with an & in it

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.[Companies]
WHERE CONTAINS(Name,'&')

select * FROM [Companies]
WHERE FREETEXT(Name,'&')
```

both of these do not return any results. I would have to use

```
select * FROM [Companies]
WHERE Name like '%&%'
```

but from my understanding is like does a full table scan that can be slow. So I am not sure how this is going to effect my site speed when I am search through around 5 million records.

I know there is elastic search but I am afraid that is going to take me too long to learn and I am on a tight deadline so I need something that can work for the interim and then I can strive towards something better.

Edit

I should add another use case that I need to handle is something like a product (think of a TV what has almost the same model number but some letters at the end) number like

```
Product A - 123456
Product B - 123456A
Product C - 123456B
```

So basically if someone types in "123456A" then all 3 results should come back and this is something I am not sure if "like" can do.

Comment: are you looking for the & in a specific column or all columns ?

Comment: You will have to do a table table scan unless the search criteria is static and you flag these entries during insertion.

Comment: try a PatIndex https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/patindex-workbench/

Comment: @SimonPrice - in this case it will be 1 column,  & couple be anything though it is a user driven search. If they just type in 1 character it should yield a huge amount of results. In the future I may be doing in other areas multi column searches but I have not gotten that far yet.

Comment: Ive done a similar thing at a bank I used to work at. I will see if i can dig out the code